# C# Xamarin android Intents and readLine()

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building trivia application and I created form activity Question.

So when the user press the right button it reopens the activity.
I want it will read the next lines and no the same ones what to do?

```
private void ShowQuestion()
{
    string content;
    AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
    StreamReader txt = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Test12.txt"), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));
    StreamReader csv = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Ans12.csv"), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));
    QuestionText.Text = txt.ReadLine();
    Button1.Text = txt.ReadLine();
    Button2.Text = txt.ReadLine();
    Button3.Text = txt.ReadLine();
    Button4.Text = txt.ReadLine();
    answer = csv.ReadLine();
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(answer == "א")
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Questions));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better? You have an activity A that read the first line and with a "right" button you open a "questions" activity that read the second line?

Comment: activity A is the same activity as activity "questions" im like opening the same activity.. (in end i just want the same activity with another question, that i get with read line but now its just read the same lines)

Comment: I think you have not to reopen the same activity. if A is open and you have to change the value in a "control", set this value.

Comment: how? split the function to only readLines and call it every time pressing the "right"
 button?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like

```
    StreamReader txt = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Test12.txt"), Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        // ...

        // First line
        Button1.Text = txt.ReadLine();

    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // other lines
        Button1.Text = txt.ReadLine();

    }
```

let me know...

Comment: its too simple.. its an trivia app
i have text view, and 4 buttons answers..
and also i need to read line from correct answer file
so i need all this 
`Button1.Text = txt.ReadLine();
            Button2.Text = txt.ReadLine();
            Button3.Text = txt.ReadLine();
            Button4.Text = txt.ReadLine();
            answer = csv.ReadLine();`
need to be updated

Comment: and also in thats way i'm loosing the back button function,
so i cant return to last question.
Maybe i need a slider for that... 
I searched a lot and its like android don't have much information in the internet like the basic c# and other languages :(